# Featured Image option is not showing in custom post types

Tags: wordpress

i've created a custom post type but the featured image option is not showing up on the right side. it is visible on the post and pages but not on the custom post types. i've checked the screen option its not showing there also i've also tried in functions.php

```
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
```

Please Help any alternative way or plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

Check your custom post type code, there should be

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
```

in it.

If you can not check it out.

or try below code in function.php

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **add the name of your new custom post type at the current theme**.

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page', 'movies','the_name_of_your_new_CPT')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Thumbnail Support when defining the post type...

```
'supports'=> array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
```

just refer the below link :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type